# Can I disconnect a dishwasher from a GFI and leave the circuit otherwise intact?

Tags: electrical, wiring

my dishwasher is wired into a GFI outlet under my sink. Can I remove the wires that go to the dishwasher and leave the other wires intact to use the GFI outlet ?

Comment: Yes. To the GFCI device, no wires to the dishwasher looks exactly like wires to a dishwasher that is stopped.

Comment: Depending on the age and State this is in a GFCI may not be required for the dishwasher, removing the dishwasher wiring would not be a problem even with the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

So your Dish washer is wired through as a load or wired in parallel and down line from the GFCI ?

Just curious your reason why you want to do this? Perhaps there might be another issue you have and your resolution might need some additional information so you can accomplish all your goals correctly ?

Now after those questions the answers based on just disconnecting the washer.

Yes you can un-wire the dish washer from the GFCI as long as nothing unusual was done in the initial wiring. In other words the GFCI must be up-line from the dish washer as one would expect in a proper installation.

If the installation was not proper you can still do what you want, but will need to rework your wiring to the GFCI.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn the power off to the branch circuit supplying the GFCI and dishwasher.
2. Locate remove the dishwasher wiring from the GFCI.

I'm including a picture I found that shows how the typical GFCI is wired. Notice that there is a line side and load side. Anything that is connected to the line side will not be protected by the GFCI, it is just a feed through. Everything plugged into the face of the GFCI, and everything connected to the load side terminals will be protected by the GFCI.(http://www.electriciansmesaaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/How-To-Wire-A-GFCI-Outlet.png)

Answer (score 0):

As to the "why" question; At one point it was acceptable to have the one GFCI outlet under the sink that would feed the dishwasher that was hard wired to it on the load side, plus have an outlet for a garbage disposal, under the theory that one would not run both at the same time.